# Detecting overlapped paths in Android

Tags: android

[image]I want to know if there is some way to detect if a currently drawn path touches/crosses an existing path. The existing path is either drawn or part of background image.
It would also be helpful, if I am able to find this *after* the current path is completely drawn.
In worst scenario, can I do some pixel-by-pixel checking to see if two paths are touching?

Comment: Adding a link to a screenshot of how it looks and some references to whats seen could help clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a path to define the line, then set a android.graphics.Region to that path. Later check all regions against each other wether they intersect or not by

```
region1.op(region2, Op.INTERSECT);
```

Comment: This will surely not work since a region is a closed path, and he isn't drawing closed paths at all times ? Or am I missing something here ?

Comment: If he draws something, it will have a width in both x & y dimension. He could build a closed path around it, at least being one pixed in width.

Comment: Any idea how can I create Path from a PointF[] array? I have got the coordinates of all points in this array.

Comment: This did not work in case of a closed path. Still gets my vote a optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the lines in a List, and then check the line you are drawing against every line in the list to see if it intersects. You will find plenty of answers on how to detect line intersection here on stackoverflow.

```
    ArrayList<Pair<Pair<Integer,Integer>,Pair<Integer,Integer>>> lineList = new ArrayList<Pair<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Pair<Integer, Integer>>>();

    // add all your lines to the list
    // lineList.add(line);

    // handle the last line
    int startX = 10;
    int startY = 20;
    int endX = 40;
    int endY = 50;

    Pair<Integer,Integer> lineStart = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(startX, startY);
    Pair<Integer,Integer> lineEnd = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(startX, startY);
    Pair<Pair<Integer,Integer>,Pair<Integer,Integer>> lastLine = new Pair<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Pair<Integer, Integer>>(lineStart, lineEnd);

    for(Pair<Pair<Integer,Integer>,Pair<Integer,Integer>> l: lineList){
        // if "lastLine" intersects "l" do you stuff
    }
```

Comment: I wonder how does one save a line in list. I save coordinates of all pixels of the line?

Comment: just save a pair of pairs.

        int startX = 10;
        int startY = 20;
        int endX = 40;
        int endY = 50;
        
        Pair<Integer,Integer> lineStart = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(startX, startY);
        Pair<Integer,Integer> lineEnd = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(startX, startY);
        Pair<Pair<Integer,Integer>,Pair<Integer,Integer>> line = new Pair(lineStart, lineEnd);

Comment: This won't work for a curved line, right? I'm sorry if that was not implied from the question.

Comment: will work for any lines and objects that you can do a 'if "lastLine" intersects "l" do you stuff' test on. so should work for any geometric shapes.